# Webdriverio Invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm getting 2023-05-18T11:47:28.780Z ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///C:/webdriver-test/wdio.conf.js: Invalid or unexpected token
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error while executing the test in saucelabs from my local using mocha framework.

I'm using node js v18.12.1  and npm version 8.19.2.

Can you please help me?

I followed the https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7139 but didn't help me.